# Specifying image size in em with rounding

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an icon I generate through a background image:

```
.icon
{
background-size:1.33em 1.33em
background-image:url(...) no-repeat center;
width:1.33em
height:1.33em
}
```

This works pretty well except that the generated size is often not a whole number (if font-size = 14px for example, I end up with 18.62 for width/height. The image is svg, but it ends up not looking great because the end cap is on a sub pixel edge. Is there a way to use this em strategy (which gives me the desired result of changing with font size), but rounding to a whole number?

Comment: You'll probably need Javascript/ jQuery for that... is that a problem?

Comment: CSS can't do that kind of calculation, period.

Comment: Yeah, it would be extraordinarily hard to do even with JS, as there's no event for text-size change. You could maybe handle it onload, but if the user changed the text-size afterward, everything would be off.